# Spring validation class and Hibernate validator annotations together

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation, annotations

I need to validate my JSP form. Hibernate validator with JSR 303 annotations is great for simple validation (like @NotEmpty). For more complex validation I need validator class.
But JSR 303 built in annotations don't do anything when I've injected my own validator!

How is possible to use annotations and class validation together?

JSP form:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%-- ... --%>
<div>
    <c:url var="address" value="/form" />
    <c:if test="${not empty message}">${message}</c:if>   
    <form:form action="${address}" method="POST" commandName="user">            
        <%-- ... --%>
        <form:label path="nickname">Nickname</form:label>
        <form:input type="text" path="nickname" />
        <form:errors path="nickname" cssClass="error"></form:errors>

        <form:label path="password">Password</form:label>
        <form:input type="password"  path="password" />
        <form:errors path="password" cssClass="error"></form:errors>

        <form:label path="password2">Password</form:label>
        <form:input type="password" path="password2" />

        <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form:form>
</div>
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User implements Serializable {
    // ...

    @NotEmpty(message="Missing name!")
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @NotEmpty
    @javax.validation.constraints.Size.List(value = { 
            @Size(min=5, message="Min 5 chars!"),
            @Size(max=10, message="Max 10 chars!")
            })
    @Column(name = "nickname", nullable = false)
    private String nickname;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Transient
    @NotEmpty
    private String password2;

    public User() {}
    // setters and getters...
}
```

Validator:

```
@Component
public class FormValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return User.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {

        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "password", "password.not.empty", "Enter password!");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "password2", "password.not.empty");

        User u = (User) target;
        if ( ! u.getPassword().equals(u.getPassword2()) ) {
            errors.rejectValue("password", "password.not.equals");  
        }       
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class FormController {

    @Autowired
    private UserManager userManager;

    @RequestMapping(value="/form", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(ModelMap model) { 
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());     
        return "register"; 
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/form", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registerSave(ModelMap model,  @Valid @ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result) {     
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("message", "ERROR");
            return "register";          
        }
        user.setPassword(password);
        /...
        userManager.save(user);     
        model.addAttribute("message", "OK");

        return "register"; 
    }

    @InitBinder("user")
    protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {       
        binder.setValidator(new FormValidator());       
    }
}
```

Comment: On a side note, you are adding your own instance of `FormValidator` here `binder.setValidator(new FormValidator());` instead of adding the instance managed by Spring through `@Component`.

Comment: I add "@Autowired private FormValidator val;" and use it: "protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) { binder.setValidator(val); }". It crash while compilation time: http://pastebin.com/LYSxxqcu

Comment: That's not a compile time error, it's a run time error. It seems you haven't component scanned the package that contains the FormValidator.

Comment: Now "@Autowired FormValidator" works, but JSR 303 built in annotations still don't do anything. :-(